# Which character in comics stayed dead the longest?

Tags: marvel, dc

Many characters die in comics, only to come back to life later, in some form or another. Which one stayed dead for the longest period of time.

To qualify, the character must:

- Must have existed in comics before death.
- Have been implied dead.
- Come back to life (Any form of resurrection is accepted including *was-never-dead*)
- Return in the same continuity (the returned character must be the same as the dead one, not just appear in an alternate universe)
- Time is measured in the real world, i.e. the difference in time between the publishing dates of the two comics.
- While any comic publishing company is okay, an ideal answer would also mention the longest for both Marvel and DC

### Which character in comics stayed dead the longest?

Comment: My guesses:  Thomas and Martha Wayne, Uncle Ben Parker, Bucky Barnes.  I'm not sure if Ben ever came back, and I think the Waynes only came back in alternate realities.  Bucky seems to be the best bet.

Comment: Captain America would have to be a good candidate - from WWII to present.

Comment: @WadCheber Good point on Bucky Barnes.  He went missing earlier and returned later than Steve Rogers.

Comment: @WadCheber did Thomas Wayne, Martha Wayne, and Uncle Ben Parker come back to life?

Comment: @JaneS I'm going by publishing date, so Captain America is only about 9 years

Comment: Barry Allen was dead for a while I think.

Comment: There was a "rule":  "The only people in comics who stay dead are Uncle Ben, Bucky, and Jason Todd".  That rule was later broken re:  Bucky and Jason Todd.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comic_book_death

Comment: I'll probably accept the first answer that has A)longest Marvel character B)longest DC character C)Pictures of the death and revival D)Dates